# The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes (SQL: ALTER TABLE product_translations ADD FULLTEXT(name))

Tags: sql, mariadb

You can help me with this error i dont know to change to MyISAM engine, I see other post with this error.
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1214 The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes (SQL: ALTER TABLE product_translations ADD FULLTEXT(name))

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductTranslationsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product_translations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('locale');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->text('short_description')->nullable();

            $table->unique(['product_id', 'locale']);
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE product_translations ADD FULLTEXT(name)');
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('product_translations');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add which database you are using

Comment: @nbk Server: Localhost via UNIX socket Server Type: MariaDB Server Connection: SSL is not being used Documentation Server version: 5.5.68-MariaDB - MariaDB Server Protocol version: 10 –

Comment: can you upgrade your version, it may be only a bug in the verion.

Comment: I have ssh terminal, can you update from there? in plesk host @nbk

Comment: sure see for example https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213403429--How-to-upgrade-MySQL-5-5-to-5-6-5-7-or-MariaDB-5-5-to-10-x-on-Linux-